# How to plot time using pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science

I have a csv with two columns, one with week day names and one with time of login of the employee. How do I plot this using matplotlib or pyplot ? not able to get how to plot the time in Y coordinate. the time data is like "23/02/2017 at 11:30 PM".

Do I need to make changes to the data or Can I plot it as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the time using datetime, and then plot the formatted date directly using pyplot. An example code.

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

sampleTime = "23/02/2017 at 11:30 PM"
timeFormatted = datetime.strptime(sampleTime, "%d/%m/%Y at %I:%M %p")
print(timeFormatted)

plt.scatter(timeFormatted, 0)

# reshape X labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
showFormat = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(showFormat)

plt.show()
```